the find command is returning permission denied
I'm running the command sudo find . | cpio -o -H newc > ../init.cpio and it returning:
-bash: ../init.cpio: Permission denied.

I don't know how to fix this or what else to try. It works fine when I run the same command in a different directory. I'm following a tutorial and when they do it in the video they get no errors and the command works perfectly giving the exact output needed. I tried to look it up and find people with the same issue but the fixes do not work.

The find command is not returning "permission denied", the shell is - because you do not have permission to redirect output to a file in the parent directory ../. See for example How to solve "permission denied" when using sudo with redirection in Bash?

This question is similar to: How to solve "permission denied" when using sudo with redirection in Bash?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
